# Discord Auto role when joining a server

Tags: discord.js

I am using the v12 and this is what I have tried so far:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
 guildMember.roles.add(
  guildMember.guild.roles.find((r) => r.name === 'Newbie')
 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Discord JS v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods such as `GuildMember.roles.find`. You will now have to directly ask for cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods. (`GuildMember.roles.cache.find`);

---

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", guildMember => { // Detecting when a GuildMember joins the guild.
    const Role = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Newbie"); // Getting the Role by name.
    if (!Role) return console.log("Invalid Role"); // Checking if the Role exists.

    guildMember.roles.add(Role.id).catch(error => console.log(error)); // Adding the Role to the GuildMember.
});
```

Comment: A little note; the `add` method on the GuildMemberRoleManager accepts a RoleResolvable as parameter, which can either be a Snowflake or a Role. Meaning you don't necessarily need `.add(Role.id)` but `.add(Role)` would work as well. Don't know if there's an advantage using either method over the other, but it's nice to have the options I suppose